# ViewPager scroll X position always returns 0

Tags: android-layout, scrollview

I have two Viewpagers one above the other in my layout file.
Bottom viewpager has 3 imageviews and the top view pager is empty with transparent background.
I want to pass the scroll event from top pager to bottom pager to see the paging.
Below is the code, and is not working properly.
**getScrollX** always **returns 0**, please let me know the solution.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_screen);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.bottomPager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setPageMargin(5);
        //pager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.color.white);
        //pager.setClipChildren(false);         

         bottomPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.bottomPager);
         topPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.topPager);

         topPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                bottomPager.scrollTo(v.getScrollX(), v.getScrollY());
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                    Log.i("LaunchScreen.onCreate()", "inside topPager touch ###########");
                    Log.i("LaunchScreen.onCreate()", "X : "+v.getScrollX()+" Y : "+v.getScrollY());
                }               
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```